# Hacer filtrado de busqueda en laravel desde por medio de una API

Tags: laravel, filtro, busqueda

Buen día, tengo mucho intentando con esto y no he podido.

Tengo una web para una inmobiliaria, la cuestión es que los datos los consumo desde una api.

quiero realizar un filtrado de busqueda que tengo en la vista, pero la cosa es que todos los datos los consumo por medio de una api,y no sé cómo realizar el filtrado.

este es mi código

```php
public function buscarInmuebles(Request $request)
    {
        $page = $request->page;
        $searchBox = $request->searchBox;
        $totalItem = 50;
        $min_price = ($request->precioInicial ? : '0');
        $max_price = ($request->precioFinal ? : '100000000');
        $min_construction = ($request->metroInicial ? : '0');
        $max_construction = ($request->metroFinal ? : '100000000');

        $property_type = $request->property_type;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.easybroker.com/v1/properties?page='.$page.'&limit='.$totalItem.'&search%5Boperation_type%5D='.$property_type.'&search%5Bmin_price%5D='.$min_price.'&search%5Bmax_price%5D='.$max_price.'&search%5Bmin_construction_size%5D='.$min_construction.'&search%5Bmax_construction_size%5D='.$max_construction.'&search%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=published',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'X-Authorization: 4lipvoprbio9xxju7t4y089lxyad2n',
                'Cookie: rp=api.easybroker.com; source=api.easybroker.com'
            ),
        ));

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($resp, true);

        $totalPaginas = ceil($response['pagination']['total']/$totalItem);

        return view('v2/propiedades', compact('response','totalPaginas','page','min_price','max_price','searchBox'));
    }
```

Este

Comment: listo, ya edité.

Answer (score 0):

**Paso 1: Modificar/Agregar las rutas**
En el archivo `routes/web.php` agrega estas lineas (NOTA: No olvides cambiar el nombre de tu controlador)

```php
Route::get('inmuebles', [TuControladorController::class, 'inmuebles']);
Route::post('consultar-inmuebles', [TuControladorController::class, 'consultarInmuebles'])->name('inmueble.query');
```

**Paso 2: Agregar los metodos del controlador**
En el controlador agrega estos dos metodos

```php
   // retorna la vista con el formulario para la busqueda
    public function inmuebles()
    {
        return view('v2.inmuebles');
    }

    // realiza la consulta y retorna la vista con el resultado de la consulta
    public function consultarInmuebles(Request $request)
    {
        // PASO 1: ANTES DE ASIGNAR LAS VARIABLES DEBES VALIDAR PARA MAS INFO DE COMO VALIDAR MIRA 
        // https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation
        $request->validate([
            "page" => "required|numeric",
            "min_price" => "required|numeric",
            "max_price" => "required|numeric"
            // ETC AQUI CONTINUAMOS VALIDANDO TODOS LOS CAMPOS DEL FORMULARIO
        ]);

        // PASO 2: DESPUES PROCEDEMOS A ASIGNAR LOS VALORES A LAS VARIABLES

        $page = $request->input('page');
        // $searchBox = $request->searchBox;
        $totalItem = 50;
        $min_price = $request->input('min_price');
        $max_price = $request->input('max_price');
        // $min_construction = ($request->metroInicial ? : '0');
        // $max_construction = ($request->metroFinal ? : '100000000');
        // $property_type = $request->property_type;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            // CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.easybroker.com/v1/properties?page='.$page.'&limit='.$totalItem.'&search%5Boperation_type%5D='.$property_type.'&search%5Bmin_price%5D='.$min_price.'&search%5Bmax_price%5D='.$max_price.'&search%5Bmin_construction_size%5D='.$min_construction.'&search%5Bmax_construction_size%5D='.$max_construction.'&search%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=published',
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.easybroker.com/v1/properties?page={$page}&limit=2&search%5Boperation_type%5D=a&search%5Bmin_price%5D={$min_price}&search%5Bmax_price%5D={$max_price}&search%5Bmin_construction_size%5D=0&search%5Bmax_construction_size%5D=10000000&search%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=published",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'X-Authorization: 4lipvoprbio9xxju7t4y089lxyad2n',
                'Cookie: rp=api.easybroker.com; source=api.easybroker.com'
            ),
        ));

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($resp, true);

        $totalPaginas = ceil($response['pagination']['total']/$totalItem);

        // return $resp;
        return view('v2/propiedades')->with('JSON', json_decode($resp));
    }
```

**Paso 3: Crea las vistas**
Ya por ultimo agrega estas dos vista en la carpeta `resources/view/v2`

Vista 1: `inmueble.blade.php`

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <H1>VISTA DE FORMULARIO DE BUSQUEDA</H1>
    <form action="{{ route('inmueble.query') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('POST')
        <label for="page">Page</label>
        <input type="text" name="page" required>

        <label for="min_price">Min Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="min_price" required>

        <label for="max_price">Mx Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="max_price" required>
        <button type="submit">CONSULTAR</button>
        {{-- ETC AQUI SIGUE AGRENADO MAS INPUT CON CRITERIOS DE BUSQUEDA DE LA URL --}}
    </form>
@endsection
```

Vista 2: `propiedades.blade.php`

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>ESTE ES LA RESPUESTA JSON PASADA A LA VISTA</h1>
    @dump($JSON)

    <H1>ESTE ES LA MENRA EN QUE SE ACCEDE A UN ELEMENTO EN EL DOC JSON</H1>
    <p>Public id: {{ $JSON->{'content'}[0]->{"public_id"} }}</p>
    
@endsection
```

NOTA: utilizo la sintaxis de laravel 9 (no especificaste que version de laravel usas pero no creo que tengas problemas si los tienes edita la pregunta y agrega los detalles parayo poder editar la respuesta), si mi respuesta es correcta no olvides marcarla como correcta.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó perfectamente